# Sort and reverse not working on list

Tags: python, list, sorting

I've created this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import csv

with open("files/usernames.csv", "r") as fh1:
    reader = csv.reader(fh1)
    usernames = map(tuple, reader)
    usernames.sort()
    print usernames
```

Problem is that `usernames` list never gets sorted. I've tried with `sorted(usernames)` but still no sorting.

usernames.csv:

> fry,bender,zoidberg,leela,hermes,nibbler,amy

Comment: @NightShadeQueen Yes

Comment: `print len(usernames)`.

Comment: You are sorting a list containing one tuple with the usernames. The super fast answers are pointing you in the right direction.

Comment: @scorreia oh, that was the problem, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `usernames` isn't a list (it's a tuple with one item I think) so sorting it won't achieve anything.

If that's really all that's in `usernames.csv` don't bother with the `csv` module, just read the file and split the line on the comma, then sort;

```
with open("files/usernames.csv", "r") as fh1:
    usernames = fh1.read().split(",")
    usernames.sort()

print(usernames)
```

Comment: Thank for your simple and elegant solution, problem is solved!

Comment: For the case that you need the reversed list, you can use the `reversed()` functions as in `reversed(usernames.sort())`

Answer (score 0):

This happens because `usernames` is a list of tuples , and it has only 1 tuple in it , if there is only 1 line in the csv. It may look like -

```
[('fry', 'bender', 'zoidberg', 'leela', 'hermes', 'nibbler', 'amy')]
```

So, when you are asking python to sort the list, it is already sorted, as it only contains 1 element, 1 tuple .

Maybe you should create a list of usernames. Example -

```
with open("files/usernames.csv", "r") as fh1:
    reader = csv.reader(fh1)
    usernames = []
    for u in reader:
        usernames.extend(u)
    usernames.sort()
    print usernames
```

Or if it has only one line -

```
with open("files/usernames.csv", "r") as fh1:
    reader = csv.reader(fh1)
    usernames = list(reader)[0]
    usernames.sort()
    print usernames
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a list of tuples with `map(tuple, reader)`, so you aren't sorting a list, but a list of tuples. You can reorder the tuples how you wish, but all of your values lie in one tuple. Tuples are also immutable, so you can not sort a tuple in place.

Try reading your values into a list and sorting the list of strings.

Answer (score -1):

`tuples` aren't meant for sorting. Use numpy arrays or lists:

```
import csv
import numpy as np

with open("usernames.csv", "r") as fh1:
    reader = csv.reader(fh1)

    usernames = map(np.array, reader)[0]
    print usernames
    usernames.sort()
    print usernames

>> ['fry' 'bender' 'zoidberg' 'leela' 'hermes' 'nibbler' 'amy']
>> ['amy' 'bender' 'fry' 'hermes' 'leela' 'nibbler' 'zoidberg']
```

**Edit**:
Here's another solution which might be considered a bit more concise:

```
import numpy as np
usernames = np.loadtxt('usernames.csv', dtype=str, delimiter=',') 
usernames.sort()
```

Comment: Why do you create a list, and then pick only the first element? Seems wasteful.

Comment: It's just the smallest modification to the OPs question and his approach.

Comment: Why not show them a better approach? People come here expecting to find reasonable code in answers.

Comment: I added another approach which I find to be more intuitive. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score -1):

You can use your old cost mostly you just need a couple extra lines to make the list-of-lists become a list and then back to strings:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import csv

with open("files/usernames.csv", "r") as fh1:
    reader = csv.reader(fh1)
    usernames = map(tuple, reader)
    usernames = map(list, usernames[0])
    usernames.sort()
    usernames = map(''.join, usernames)
    print usernames
```